# Shader and OpenGL ES in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl-es, shader

I have a shader that "cuts" the 3D model depending on the position of plane(s) (it sets the side above the panel to transprent).

The shader works very well in editor. However, it does work on a mobile device lets call it A) on Android, but it does not work on a other device (lets call it B) also on Android.

Device A: `Open GL ES 2.0 build 1.12@2701748` | colors are good, "cutting" is good
Device B: `Open GL ES 2.0 build 16.05001` | colors are lost (pink), cutting does not work

Can someone give me a clue about how to find out what is making the shader not working?

Here is the shader code:

```
Shader "CrossSection/GenericThreePlanesBSP" {
    Properties{
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _CrossColor("Cross Section Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _PlaneNormal("Plane1Normal",Vector) = (0,1,0,0)
        _PlanePosition("Plane1Position",Vector) = (0,0,0,1)
    }
    SubShader{
    Tags{ "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
    //LOD 200

    Cull Back
    CGPROGRAM
    // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

    // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;    
        float3 worldPos;
    };

    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
    fixed4 _Color;
    fixed4 _CrossColor;
    fixed3 _PlaneNormal;
    fixed3 _PlanePosition;

    float _RealArraySize;
    float _MaxArraySize = 100;
    float4 _Positions[100];
    float4 _Normals[100];

    bool checkVisability(fixed3 worldPos)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= _RealArraySize - 1 ; i++)
        {
            // Will check if the point's position is above the plane
            // If true --> Hide the point
            if (dot(worldPos - _Positions[i], _Normals[i]) > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
        if (checkVisability(IN.worldPos))discard;
        fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
    }
    ENDCG

    Cull Front
    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf NoLighting  noambient

    struct Input {
        half2 uv_MainTex;
        float3 worldPos;    
    };

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    fixed4 _Color;
    fixed4 _CrossColor;
    fixed3 _PlaneNormal;
    fixed3 _PlanePosition;
    float _RealArraySize;
    float _MaxArraySize = 100;
    float4 _Positions[100];
    float4 _Normals[100];

    bool checkVisability(fixed3 worldPos)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= _RealArraySize - 1 ; i++)
        {
            // Will check if the point's position is above the plane
            // If true --> Hide the point
            if (dot(worldPos - _Positions[i], _Normals[i]) > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    fixed4 LightingNoLighting(SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, fixed atten)
    {
        fixed4 c;
        c.rgb = s.Albedo;
        c.a = s.Alpha;
        return c;
    }

    void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
    {
        if (checkVisability(IN.worldPos))discard;
        o.Albedo = _CrossColor;    
    }
    ENDCG

    }
    //FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Edit: `SystemInfo.graphicsShaderLevel` returns 30 for both devices.